# how to create submenus in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, submenu

I have a module that adds a link to main menu. When I click on that link the requested page gets loaded (a .js and .html file).

My main menu looks like this:

- My link

My code looks like this:

```
<?php

/**                                                                                                                                           
 * Implements hook_menu()                                                                                                                     
 */
function kl_menu(){
  $items = array();

  $items['simple_link'] = array(
   'title'            => t('my link'),
   'page callback'    => 'build_page',
   'access arguments' => array('access content'),
   'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
   'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

/*                                                                                                                                            
 * build_page                                                                                                                   
 */
function build_page() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'kl') . '/mypage.js', 'file');
   return  ( file_get_contents( drupal_get_path('module', 'kl').'/mypage.html') );
}
```

Now I would like add a submenu instead of a simple plain link so that my main menu would look like this:

- My submenu

  - my sublink1
  - my sublink2

I would like that when I click on  "my submenu" then this sub menu expands displaying more links. Then when I reclick on my submenu I would like it to collapse.

I am pretty new to drupal php etc.

How can I acheive that. I am using garland theme.

Thanks

baba

Comment: Hey Baba check this out: http://api.drupal.org/comment/33303#comment-33303

Answer (score 0):

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function kl_menu() {
  $items['simple_link'] = array(
    'title'            => t('my link'),
    'page callback'    => 'kl_build_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items['simple_link/my_sublink_1'] = array(
    'title'            => t('my sub link 1'),
    'page callback'    => 'mymodule_sub_page_1',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items['simple_link/my_sublink_2'] = array(
    'title'            => t('my sub link 2'),
    'page callback'    => 'mymodule_sub_page_1',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function kl_theme() {
  $template_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'kl') . '/templates';

  return array(
    // File would be <module path>/templates/kl-build-page.tpl.php
    'kl_build_page' => array(
      'path' => $template_path,
      'template' => 'kl-build-page')
    ),
    // File would be <module path>/templates/kl-sub-page-1.tpl.php
    'sub_page_1' => array(
      'path' => $template_path,
      'template' => 'kl-sub-page-1')
    ),
    // File would be <module path>/templates/kl-sub-page-2.tpl.php
    'sub_page_2' => array(
      'path' => $template_path,
      'template' => 'kl-sub-page-2')
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Callback for main build page.
 */
function kl_build_page() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'kl') . '/mypage.js', 'file');
  return  theme('kl_build_page');
}

/**
 * Page callback for sub page 1
 */
function kl_sub_page_1() {
  return theme('kl_sub_page_1');
}

/**
 * Page callback for sub page 2
 */
function kl_sub_page_2() {
  return theme('kl_sub_page_2');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. So using MENU_LOCAL_TASK does not display any subitems and does not show "my simple link" as expandable either. Using MENU_NORMAL_ITEM instead works. The subitems are displayed but when i click on the sub items I get a blank page. Then I get the message: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'build_page' not found or invalid function name in menu_execute_active_handler() (line 517 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kl-local/includes/menu.inc).

Comment: I updated my answer to account for your feedback on the menu type, and I re-worked it to use a more standard use of naming conventions and Drupal's template system. You would need to flush cache to get the new hook_theme() to pick up. The code is un-tested, but it should give you an idea on how the menu callbacks relate to the callback functions.